# Bash script to search multiple files with a string mentioned in a different file, then copy those files into a new directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple files recorded per date. At the end of every day, I need to run a script to grep those files which contain particular numbers mentioned in a different file, then copy all those files (CSV records) which contain matching UID records to another file location.

Working Dir = `/var/output`
Search file name = `/var/output/UID.txt`

```
##Cat UID.txt
639867675
123466490
123334555
```

filenames = `CSV_name_date.csv`
Each filename is unique, and in  a day I get roughly around 5000 files.

I'm using this code,

```
grep -f uid.txt -e stringpattern -l | xargs cp -t /var/output2/
```

I need to run a search on a particular date, the script should ask you which date you want to run and run the search on files of those dates only.

Comment: just run `grep` on all the files at once, like adding something like `CSV*.csv` at its end. Also the `-e stringpattern` seems redundant with -f. If there are too many, use a `find ... -type f |xargs grep -H ...` construct. Yes that will be two `xargs` in the same line

Comment: Hi, A.B, how can I set in a script to run on particular dates only. I don't want to run it all files.

Comment: Well that's what I wrote. Did you try?